# Responsive navbar collapsing animation with AngularStrap

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-strap

I'm trying to recreate collapsible [Bootstrap responsive navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) with  AngularStrap.

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZTil36zmO5oOQyr52uU5?p=preview):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container" bs-collapse start-collapsed="true">
      <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" bs-collapse-toggle>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div bs-collapse-target>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`bs-collapse` directive fits Bootstrap `navbar` quite easily, but it doesn't support collapsing animation out of the box.

How it can be done?

Is there a way to do this following Bootstrap workflow and utilizing its [.collapsing](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.4/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L3400) animation instead of re-inventing the wheel (but simple LESS/SASS mixin that makes use of it is also fine)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the animations working, you may need to include `angular-motion` AND the `angular-motion.min.css` file that's part of the [angular-motion package](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-motion). The reference to the CSS file isn't part of the main documentation. I'm pretty sure I found references to it here on StackOverflow when I had similar issues.

Comment: Great, looks like exactly what is needed. The last time I've checked AngularStrap the author didn't bother to promote this essential addon in the repo (and now he does). The link is broken btw.

Comment: I hope it fixes your problem and thanks for the heads up on the link. It's fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm still getting this to work. I'm including the `angular-motion.min.css` file and `angular-animate.min.js`. Then I'm injecting `ngAnimate` in my module. Still no luck. Do you mind taking a look at my fiddle and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/beedaan/8dowyqmL/light/