# How do I animate AngularStrap Collapse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ng-animate, angular-strap

I have a navbar collapse working with AngularStrap, but the collapsing is not animated.  I *thought* I was doing everything correctly by injecting the `ngAnimate` library and adding the `data-animation='am-collapse'` attribute to my `bs-collapse` directive.  How do I properly animate the collapse?

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beedaan/8dowyqmL/)

Comment: without looking into your code: did you add css (`.animate.ng-enter`, `.animate.ng-leave` etc.)?

Comment: @Vienna, I haven't.  I must have missed those classes.  Where should I add those?

Comment: here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/AAv3LfwkhPWyW4Den4DL?p=preview

Comment: It isn't that simple. And there's separate angular-motion package to support animations in angular-strap, as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30564475/responsive-navbar-collapsing-animation-with-angularstrap). And you should probably know this, since you left a comment there.

Comment: @estus The angular-motion library in included in my fiddle.  What am I missing to make the animation work properly?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the CSS animation code

```
.collapse.am-collapse {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.collapse.am-collapse.in-remove {
    animation-name: collapse;
    display: block;
}
.collapse.am-collapse.in-add {
    animation-name: expand;
  }
}
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beedaan/9ptbz8hm/)